# I encountered an error when trying to install mod_wsgi apache module

Tags: python, postgresql, apache, mod-wsgi, pgadmin-4

I'm using Bitnami WAPP (Windows, Apache, PostgreSQL, PHP) Stack as a development environment and I need to install mod_wsgi in order to use pgAdmin4 - an RDBMS for PostgreSQL (similar to MySQL Workbench). But when I tried to install it using `pip install mod_wsgi` it returns the following error:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install mod_wsgi
Collecting mod_wsgi
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/69/5139588686eb40053f8355eba1fe18a8bee94dc3efc4e36720c73e07471a/mod_wsgi-4.6.5.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi
  Running setup.py install for mod-wsgi ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\justin~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-myppun\mod-wsgi\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\justin~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-xtudvn\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi
    copying src__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\server
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\server\management
    copying src\server\management__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\server\management
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\docs
    copying docs_build\html__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\docs
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mod_wsgi\images
    running build_ext
    building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
    error: INCLUDE environment variable is empty

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\justin~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-myppun\mod-wsgi\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\justin~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-xtudvn\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\justin~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-myppun\mod-wsgi\

I've also run this command before the above command

```
set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=C:/Bitnami/wappstack-7.1.25-0/apache2"
```

How can I fix it? Please help... Thank you!

Comment: You should use your Linux distributions package manager to install mod_wsgi, not pip.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I'm using Windows platform sir.